# Unity3d - Vuforia-Unity: How to enable or disable a virtual button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Unity3d - Vuforia-Unity: How to enable or disable a virtual button?

Comment: *`Guess I found the solution myself!!`* You should leave your question as a question and post an answer instead of editing the solution into the question.

Comment: Yes, was in a hurry! Tnx Draco18s. :)

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found the solution myself!!

### **For Unity and Vuforia:**

#### Approach #1:

As every entity in Unity is a GameObject, we can find virtual button using approach below:

To enable/disable a virtual button in C# script:

```
var myVirtualBtn = GameObject.Find("myVirtualButtonName"); // gameobject name above transform settings section
if(myVirtualBtn != null){
    myVirtualBtn.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehavior>().enabled = true; // Makes touchable virtual btn.
    myVirtualBtn.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehavior>().enabled = false; // Makes untouchable virtual btn.
}
```

#### Approach #2:

Skip registration of event handler associated with your virtual button

```
VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vbs = GetComponentsInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
    for( int i = 0; i< vbs.Length; ++i)
    {
       if(vbs[i].VirtualButtonName != "myVirtualButtonName") // Skip registration
            vbs[i].RegisterEventHandler(this);
    }
```